# C#: Unable to access Public method in a private method

Tags: c#, methods, private, public

I'm new to C# and using Forms, so forgive me if I'm not understanding how this is supposed to work.

I'm trying to create a LayoutTablePanel in a Form to eventually display some data.

In Visual Studio, I know I can drag and drop a LayoutTablePanel into the Form Designer to visually see the table get added, but to make it easier to add/edit tables, I'd like to do it from with the public Form1() level like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{       
 public Form1()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  TableLayoutPanel ClassCol = new TableLayoutPanel();
  ClassCol.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 20);
  ClassCol.Name = "ClassCol";
  ClassCol.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 400); //add a changing variable here later.
  ClassCol.TabIndex = 0;
  ClassCol.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
  Controls.Add(ClassCol);
 }

 private void toolStripLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
}
```

Now, this initializes the TableLayoutPanel at runtime, which is what I want, but I'd like to modify (dynamically add rows) later on by clicking certain buttons.  In this case, by clicking on toolStripLabel1_Click method; however, when typing in Class.Col within the private method there, it doesn't seem to have access to the iteration of the TableLayoutPanel instance I created.  If someone could help me fix this, it'd be appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit:  If I adjust the code like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{     
  TableLayoutPanel ClassCol = new TableLayoutPanel();
  ClassCol.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 20);
  ClassCol.Name = "ClassCol";
  ClassCol.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 400); //add a changing variable here later.
  ClassCol.TabIndex = 0;
  ClassCol.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
  Controls.Add(ClassCol);

 public Form1()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void toolStripLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
}
```

It says I'm using Form1.ClassCol as if it's a "type" when it's a "field".

Comment: your "ClassCol " is "dying" within the first Form1() chunk of the code. Putting it in a public method doesn't give you a "public" access to it.

Comment: in your code ClassCol is local, not public variable

Comment: Maybe move back to basics first and read up on "variable scope" and the general structure of a C# class (e.g. were can declarations go, and where does actual code go) etc. Seeing your edit it seems that you are misled in the very basics that you need to understand the code. This is not meant rude, but is just a suggestion to take it a bit slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this line:

```
TableLayoutPanel ClassCol = new TableLayoutPanel();
```

Above this line:

```
public Form1()
```

You are declaring it locally inside your `Form1()` constructor, so no other method will be able to access it. You need to declare it at class level instead of method level.

Comment: It is still accessible but by doing some tricks with the form children - far from optimal and a maintenance hell

Comment: @Machinarius - Yes, but why confuse the guy who is new to C#?

Comment: That's the main reason I didn't post any code. It just seemed unfair not to say it

Comment: He could just do `Controls.OfType<TableLayoutPanel>().First()`, assuming this is the only `TableLayoutPanel` on his form.

Comment: Controls. Single (x=>x. Name == "ClassCol") could also do it. (I'm on mobile so excuse the formatting please)

Comment: When I move the line you specified above public Form1(), it underlines everything beginning with ClassCol and when I mouseover it, it says 'Form1.ClassCol' is a "field" but is being used like a "type".

Comment: @TekGiant - No, no. You just needed to move that one line. Everything else should stay in the `public Form1()` method

Comment: Got it.  Not sure why that works that way, but it did. thanks.

Comment: @TekGiant - You are declaring it outside the local scope, but any functionality has to be within a method.